# Getting this rails error: ActionController::ParameterMissing in PostsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parameters

```
Error: ActionController::ParameterMissing in PostsController#new
```

param is missing or the value is empty: post

I'm working on a 2 model rails app and when I try to go to the "new post" link to create a post this error comes up. 
BUT none of my actual code is highlighted...a blank line is highlighted above my "private, def post-params" code.

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

**error code highlights here**

```
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :photo_url, :description, :resume)
   end
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path(@post), method: :post do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :name %><br> <%= f.text_field :name %> </p> 
  <p> <%= f.label :photo_url %><br> <%= f.text_area :photo_url %> </p>    
  <p> <%= f.label :description %><br> <%= f.text_area :description %></p>
  <p> <%= f.label :resume %><br> <%= f.text_area :resume %> </p> 
  <p> <%= f.submit %> </p> 
<% end %>
```

I have all of the correct `params` from my schema listed, so I think it might have to do with syntax or my path?

Nothing I've changed in syntax or path naming has worked so far.

Comment: can you post the form html, it sounds like there is a line missing but I need to see it. The error , I believe is coming from the params probably set in a private method that requires post, and you want to keep that, but it is not getting sent with the form most likley.

Comment: ah, sorry i'm new to stack overflow and am not sure how to add this code in html format in comments....

Comment: Update your question with the code. Don't add it here in the comments. Remove the code which is not related to the question. For example, your `destroy` method has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Also post the params hash from the stack trace so we can see what's actually coming through. The error means it should have a `:post => {...` in it and it doesn't. Show what it does have.

Comment: Please post your code in `new` method

Comment: try this in the top line "<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>" and see if that works, the "@post" is what is missing when it gets sent I believe.

Comment: I tried to change that but the error was the same. I'm using _form.html.erb for more than one page and am able to view the form in my edit page.